# RabbitMQ: dropping messages when no consumers are connected

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to setup RabbitMQ in a model where there is only one producer and one consumer, and where messages sent by the producer are delivered to the consumer only if the consumer is connected, but dropped if the consumer is not present.

Basically I want the queue to drop all the messages it receives when no consumer is connected to it.

An additional constraint is that the queue must be declared on the RabbitMQ server side, and must not be explicitly created by the consumer or the producer.

Is that possible?

I've looked at a few things, but I can't seem to make it work:

1. durable vs non-durable does not work, because it is only useful when the broker restarts. I need the same effect but on a connection.
2. setting `auto_delete` to true on the queue means that my client can never connect to this queue again.
3. `x-message-ttl` and `max-length` make it possible to lose message even when there is a consumer connected.
4. I've looked at topic exchanges, but as far as I can tell, these only affect the routing of messages between the exchange and the queue based on the message content, and can't take into account whether or not a queue has connected consumers.

The effect that I'm looking for would be something like `auto_delete` on disconnect, and `auto_create` on connect. Is there a mechanism in rabbitmq that lets me do that?

Comment: @Jesferman solution is good, based on the constraints indicated in your question. But I'm curious: why can't your consumer create the queue? Would it be ok if the queue was there, but bound (and unbound) by your consumer?

Comment: My consumer can't create the queue because I'm trying to simulate the behavior of an external broker provided by another company (for automated testing purposes). My consumer is not allowed to create queues on the external broker, so my test environment must reflect that fact.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a bit more research, I discovered that one of the assumptions in my question regarding `x-message-ttl` was wrong. I overlooked a single sentence from the RabbitMQ documentation:

> Setting the TTL to 0 causes messages to be expired upon reaching a queue unless they can be delivered to a consumer immediately
>
> https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

It turns out that the simplest solution is to set `x-message-ttl` to `0` on my queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can not doing it directly, but there is a mechanism not dificult to implement.

You have to enable the Event Exchange Plugin. This is a exchange at which your server app can connect and will receive internal events of RabbitMQ. You would be interested in the consumer.created and consumer.deleted events.

When these events are received you can trigger an action (create or delete the queue you need). More information here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your consumer is allowed to dynamically bind / unbind a queue during start/stop on the broker it should be possible by that way (e.g. queue is pre setup and the consumer binds the queue during startup to an exchange it wants to receive messages from)